# ¿Como usar ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE y DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE en hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Les comento, estoy trabajando con hibernate 4.3 en netbean con conexion a SQL y en mi base de datos tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
USUARIO(
 ID_USUARIO VARCHAR(08) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 USU VARCHAR(12)
 CLAVE VARBINARY(8000)
)
```

Antes de trabajar con hibernate encryptaba y desencryptaba mi clave con procedimiento almacenado que usaba ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE y DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE de SQL, ahora que trabajo con hibernate estaba usando los mismos procedimientos almacenados y trabaja bien, pero estaba viendo que hay forma de hacerlo de manera directa con:

```
@Column(name = "CLAVE", nullable = false)
    @ColumnTransformer(write = "ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('frase',?)", read = "DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('frase',CLAVE)")
    public byte[] getClave() {
        return this.clave;
    }
```

también probé con (y sigue sin funcionar)

```
CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('frase',CLAVE) as varchar(12))
```

Pero al hacer mi consulta y mostrar la clave me muestra caracteres y no la clave en si.

```
System.out.println("Pass 2: " + new String(usuario.getClave()));
```

Según lo que leí lo que hago esta bien, pero no me funciona alguna idea de porque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que había hecho estaba bien, mi problema fue que al mapear las tablas de la base de datos los mapeaba como archivos xml (en **hibernate.cfg.xml**)

```
<mapping resource="dao/dto/hibernate/Usuario.hbm.xml"/>
```

y no como anotaciones.

```
<mapping class="dao.dto.hibernate.Usuario"/>
```

Tener en cuenta:

```
USUARIO(
 ID_USUARIO VARCHAR(08) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 USU VARCHAR(12),
 CLAVE VARBINARY(8000),
)
```

Set y get del Pojo:

```
@Column(name = "CLAVE", nullable = false)
@ColumnTransformer(write = "ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('palabrita',?)", read = "DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('palabrita',CLAVE)")
public byte[] getClave() {
    return this.clave;
}

public void setClave(byte[] clave) {
    this.clave = clave;
}
```

al leer se debe transformar de byte[] a String y al escribir viceversa.